# R equivalent of [x[y] for x,y in zip(i,j)] in python?

Tags: python, r

I was wondering is there a R equivalent of this list comprehension of a duple in python? What it does is extract certain elements from a nested list i given indices from j:

```
i = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,4,2]]
j = [1,2,0]
whatineed = [x[y] for x,y in izip(i,j)]
```

Presumably, in R the corresponding i and j would be lists/vectors:

```
i = list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4),c(2,4,2))
j = c(2,3,1)
```

or

```
j = list(2,3,1)
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R you use `Map` function:

```
i = list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4),c(2,4,2))
j = c(2,3,1)

Map(`[`, i, j)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 2
```

You can also use `mapply` which returns a vector instead of a list:

```
mapply(`[`, i, j)
[1] 2 4 2
```

Comment: It is a tricky question. I say it can be depending on what you want.

Comment: @MeredithHu; if you are asking that question because you found htose functions all on the `Funprog` help page, then the answer is "only rarely". They are gathered together on one help page mainly because they mimic LisP functions by those names, rather than being particularly dependent on oen another for functionality.

Comment: @Psidom, a quick extension question: what if I want [x[y:] for x,y in izip(i,j)] instead? could it be done with mapply/Map similarly? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can write a customized function to do which is going to be similar to python. `Map(function(x, y) x[y:length(x)], i, j)`.